# repository for python cmath library

Tags: python-3.x, repository, cmath

I have been searching for the CMATH library for python and never seem to get the proper repository.

I have tried using pip to acquire CMATH as well using: PIP  INSTALL CMATH

and the following error is returned:  COULD NOT FIND A VERSION THAT SATISFIES THE REQUIREMENT CMATH. NO MATCHING VERSION FOUND CMATH.

I am sure there MUST be a current version for Python 3.7.1  or there might be a replacement. Any help on where to get this library would be greatly appreciated.

Poe